# How does one build WINCACHE .DLL from source files?

Tags: php, windows, dll, wincache

I downloaded `WINCACHE-1.3.7.4.tgz` from [the PECL download page](https://pecl.php.net/package/WinCache). Unpacking it i find many a C orientated source file. Compiling from source in Linux i have some experience in BUT none at all in Windows (i am running Windows 7).

The instructions on [PHP.net's WinCache pages](http://php.net/manual/en/wincache.win32build.building.php) does not seem to match the files extracted from the `.tgz'

I have looked at suggested questions

- [Creating Windows DLL from C++ source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604200/creating-windows-dll-from-c-source-files)
- [Creating php DLL from pecl source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228341/creating-php-dll-from-pecl-source-files)

but i have NO idea where to actually start off.

And thus, does anyone know how i would build WinCache .DLL from the provided source? (if at all easily possible)

Comment: Please comment to motivate why the question has been downvoted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to build this extension from source? **If not**, you can download precompiled [DLLs here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincache/files/wincache-1.3.7/). **If yes**, you have to follow [this tutorial](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) for compiling PHP extension on Windows. Basically, you have to build PHP and it will also compile extension that you will enable. After successful compilation you should be able to find required dll and use it with your running PHP.

But another question is for what do you need it? What version of PHP do you use? If 5.5+ you should consider [OPCache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) instead WinCache.

> Since the Zend Opcache extension is now in the core PHP product, the WinCache     opcode cache is disabled by default. As of PHP 5.5, the opcode cache portion of WinCache is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release of the WinCache extension.

Comment: You sir are a life saver, indeed! I could not find a location where recent builds of WinCache was available and could only get "recent" source files from the PECL download page.

This is my first round of dealing with caching in PHP and ran into WinCache first. I hoped to start there and as i learn more hopefully learn about things such as OPCache and the deprecation of the opcode caching.

Comment: wincache for Windows hasn't been updated in over a year. You can get it here, https://sourceforge.net/projects/wincache/. But I think it's a great to understand how to build it yourself. https://www.php.net/manual/en/wincache.win32build.php